# What is the location of config file in Docker 1.9?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, docker-registry

In the version 1.8 of Docker we could find the docker config file under /etc/sysconfig

However, after installing Docker 1.9 I cant see the docker config file under /etc/sysconfig

What is the new location of the config file??

Distribution: Centos 7.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you have moved from the CentOS distributed `docker` to the [docker.com](https://docker.com) `docker-engine` packages as CentOS hasn't moved to 1.9 yet.

The CentOS packages will make use of the `/etc/sysconfig` standard. Dockers packages *will not*. You will also miss out on the `docker-storage-setup` program RedHat built to deal with their unique storage requirements.

The `systemd` config in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` will show you the difference:

Docker

```
[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
```

CentOS

```
[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-network
Environment=GOTRACEBACK=crash
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon $OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS \
          $ADD_REGISTRY \
          $BLOCK_REGISTRY \
          $INSECURE_REGISTRY
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
MountFlags=slave
TimeoutStartSec=1min
Restart=on-failure
```

So then, how do I configure the `docker-engine` installed docker service?

[Docker have a page on setting up the systemd config](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options). You can go either CentOS or Docker with your config

- Docker - edit the docker-engine systemd config file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` with your required options
- Centos - copy the `EnvironmentFile` setup and then configure your options in `/etc/sysconfig/docker`.